# Custom Cells Overlapping in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I have a custom cell class called GameCell, the UI being created in storyboard. When my cells load, they load on top of each other. This problems occurs for cell.clipsToBounds YES and NO, just in different variations:

[image: cell.clipsToBound = YES]

[image: cell.clipsToBound = NO]

I have also tried [cell setClipsToBounds:(BOOL)] with no success.

Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"gameCell";

GameCell *cell = (GameCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
[cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];
NSLog(@"made a cell");
PFObject *myPartners = [self.games objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
PFUser *partner = [self.partnerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Cell profile image
cell.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
cell.profileImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

if([partner objectForKey:@"profilePic"]!=nil){
cell.profileImage.image = [partner objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
}
else {
    cell.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smile_green.png"];
} 

//Cell indicators
if((int)[myPartners objectForKey:@"sent"]==1){
    cell.myIndicator.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_icon_dbl.png"];
}
else if ([myPartners objectForKey:@"sent"]==0){
    cell.myIndicator.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_icon.png"];
}

cell.partnerName.text = [myPartners objectForKey:@"receiverName"];
cell.gameId = myPartners.objectId;

// Cell drop shadow
[cell.cellView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[cell.cellView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
[cell.cellView.layer setShadowRadius:2.0];
[cell.cellView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];

// Cell buttons
if([myPartners objectForKey:@"picture"]!=nil) {
            [cell.myPlay setEnabled:NO];
} else {
           [cell.myPlay setEnabled:YES];
}

return cell;
}
```

The view is a UITableViewController embedded in a NavigationController

Comment: It looks like you need to return a taller height for the rows of your table view (with rowHeight property or the delegate method, tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

Comment: Check this may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358831/ios-7-1-uitableviewcell-content-overlaps-with-ones-below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that the height of your cell is the `RowHeight` of your `UITableView` control.

e.g.,

Cell is designed from XIB, and the height of the view is 30, then make sure:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 30.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

use like this

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

and also check this link.

[UITableView cell Contents are disappearing and overlapping when scrolled in UITableViewcell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403147/uitableview-cell-contents-are-disappearing-and-overlapping-when-scrolled-in-uita)

Answer (score -1):

In attributes inspector cancel `Adjust Scroll view insets` option.

you need clicked view controller .